# prove that relative interior preserves product

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, products

Let $C_1 \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $C_2 \subset \mathbb R^m$ be convex sets. I want to prove that $\text{rint}(C_1\times C_2)=\text{rint}(C_1)\times \text{rint}(C_2)$.

I know that this question is already asked and answered, but I want to prove it by first proving that $\text{aff}(C_1\times C_2)=\text{aff}(C_1)\times \text{aff}(C_2)$ and then concluding that $\text{rint}(C_1\times C_2)=\text{rint}(C_1)\times \text{rint}(C_2)$.

By $\text{rint}$, I mean the [relative interior of the set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior), and by $\text{aff}$, I mean the [affine hull of the set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have that the affine hull commutes with the cartesian product, you can prove it like this:

"$\subset$":
Let $x = (x_1, x_2) \in \text{ri}(C_1 \times C_2) \subset C_1 \times C_2$.
Then there exists a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap \text{aff}(C_1 \times C_2) \subset C_1 \times C_2$.

Since $B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_1) \times B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_2) \subset B_{\varepsilon}(x)$, we have
\begin{align*}
        \left[ B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_1) \cap \text{aff}(C_1) \right]
        \times \left[ B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_2) \cap \text{aff}(C_2) \right]
        & = \left[ B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_1) \times B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_2) \right]
        \cap \left[\text{aff}(C_1) \times \text{aff}(C_2) \right] \\
        & = \left[ B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_1) \times B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_2) \right]
        \cap \text{aff}(C_1 \times C_2) \\
        & \subset B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap \text{aff}(C_1 \times C_2)
        \subset C_1 \times C_2,
    \end{align*}
so $B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_k) \cap \text{aff}(C_k) \subset C_k$ and thus $x_k \in \text{ri}(C_k)$ for $k \in \{ 1, 2 \}$.

"$\supset$":
Let $x_k \in \text{ri}(C_k)$ for $k \in \{ 1, 2 \}$.
Then there exist $\varepsilon_k > 0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon_k}(x_k) \cap \text{aff}(C_k) \subset C_k$.
Let $x := (x_1, x_2) \in C_1 \times C_2$ and $\varepsilon := \min(\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2) > 0$.
Due to $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset B_{\varepsilon}(x_1) \times B_{\varepsilon}(x_2)$ we have
\begin{align*}
        B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap \text{aff}(C_1 \times C_2)
        & = B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap \left[\text{aff}(C_1) \times \text{aff}(C_2) \right] \\
        & \subset \left[ B_{\varepsilon}(x_1) \times B_{\varepsilon}(x_2) \right] \cap \left[\text{aff}(C_1) \times \text{aff}(C_2) \right] \\
        & = \left[ B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_1) \cap \text{aff}(C_1) \right]
        \times \left[ B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x_2) \cap \text{aff}(C_2) \right] \\
        & \subset C_1 \times C_2,
    \end{align*}
so $x \in \text{ri}(C_1 \times C_2)$.